# xauth error with ssh X Forwarding

Tags: ssh, x11-forwarding, xauth

From my (Debian) Desktop machine, I am trying to ssh into a Debian Server with

```
 ssh -X remote-ip
```

After logging into the remote host, I get:

```
 /usr/bin/X11/xauth:  creating new authority file /root/.Xauthority
 /usr/bin/X11/xauth: (stdin):1:  bad display name "unix:10.0" in "remove" command
 /usr/bin/X11/xauth: (stdin):2:  bad display name "unix:10.0" in "add" command
```

And the X Forwarding doesn't work. From my Desktop I can ssh -X into other Debian servers and it works fine. I found a lot of threads discussing similar issues on google, but they all seem to fade out without a  solution, and the simple things suggested there like exporting DISPLAY or setting xhost + don't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to resolve this, even after making sure the config files were the same on the working and non working machines. As a workaround, I installed x11vnc and used the vnc protocol instead of X11.

Answer (score 1):

Try `-Y` instead of `-X`

```
ssh -Y remote-ip
```

From the ssh man page, this "Enables trusted X11 forwarding.  Trusted X11 forwardings are not subjected to the X11 SECURITY extension controls."

If this works, you can add to ~/.ssh/config:

```
Host remote-ip
ForwardX11Trusted yes
```

and you won't need to explicitly add `-Y`.

To figure out why this remote machine behaves differently from the others, take a look at the `sshd_config` file -- found in /etc/ssh/sshd_config on RedHat. I'm don't know if it's in a different location on Debian.

There's more discussion of related issues in [another SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/70051/ssh-x11-forwarding-issue) question.

Answer (score 1):

Add the host name you're connecting to your dns or hosts file. 
reconnect using `ssh -X root@hostname` rather than ip. - delete any offending keys if necessary.